# How to run python robot framework tests in phantomjs from windows?

Tags: python, phantomjs, robotframework, selenium2library

I have test written in python robot framework and it running fine in Firefox browser. how can i execute same tests in phantomjs?
I have downloaded phantomjs and added to project path.

Added below line in *init* file.

```
Suite Setup     open "phantomjs" to show "${URL}"
```

All test cases failed with this error "Text '??' did not appear in 10 seconds".
Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Can you show implementation of keyword "open "phantomjs" to show..."?

Comment: <code> open "${browser}" to show "${url}"
    open browser
    ...     ${url}
    ...     browser=${browser}
    maximize browser
    wait for page to load <code>

Comment: @soyacz please find the keyword implementation above comment. sorry about the formatting..

Comment: I assume error ou showed is from "wait for page to load".
You must see log.html to investigate why this error occurs.

Comment: @soyacz Thanks for the response.. without any changes tests are running fine in Jenkins using phantomJS. still i have same issue in local machine.